# Create Table from JSON Data with angularjs and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I have the following data as JSON:

```
{
  "Workout1": {
    "Name": "First",
    "Rounds": [
      {
        "Exercises": [
          {
            "Name": "Exercise1",
            "Repeat": 10
          },
          {
            "Name": "Exercise2",
            "Repeat": 10
          },
          {
            "Name": "Exercise3",
            "Repeat": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Exercises": [
          {
            "Name": "Exercise1",
            "Repeat": 20
          },
          {
            "Name": "Exercise2",
            "Repeat": 20
          },
          {
            "Name": "Exercise3",
            "Repeat": 20
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Exercises": [
          {
            "Name": "Exercise1",
            "Repeat": 30
          },
          {
            "Name": "Exercise2",
            "Repeat": 30
          },
          {
            "Name": "Exercise3",
            "Repeat": 30
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and I want to display it as a html table with angularjs and ng-repeat.
so that I get the following table:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Round1</th>
        <th>Round2</th>
        <th>Round3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10 Exercise1</td>
        <td>20 Exercise1</td>
        <td>30 Exercise1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10 Exercise2</td>
        <td>20 Exercise2</td>
        <td>30 Exercise2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10 Exercise3</td>
        <td>20 Exercise3</td>
        <td>30 Exercise3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

for table preview:
http://jsfiddle.net/54pD8/

my problem that the html table is working row-based.
I can iterate with ng-repeat through my Rounds and then through my excercises
but for creating a table I need always the first of each exercises then the second of each exercises and so on.

Can someone help me with this problem?

ps. if you have an idea for better layout for this data in json, your suggestions are welcome, I'm new to json (and angularjs).

Comment: updated the example below to use table and not li. Please note ng:repeat is still used.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is in Angular's official tutorial. In this tutorial Phones are loaded from a JSON file [using Angulars $http service](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) . In the code below we use **$http.get** to load a phones.json file saved in the phones directory:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);   
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
$scope.phones = data;
}); 
$scope.orderProp = 'age';
});
```

We then iterate over the phones:

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="i in phones">
    <tr><td>{{i.name}}</td><td>{{$index}}</td></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="e in i.details">
       <td>{{$index}}</td>
       <td>{{e.foo}}</td>
       <td>{{e.bar}}</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried it with the same code and it worked with a list but i neeed a table!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is due to an update on Angular or if it was a typo, but I believe the ng:repeat should be ng-repeat.  I'm getting an error when I use ng:repeat but it works with ng-repeat.  I'm using the method that includes the external google script: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>  Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Easy way to use for create dynamic header and cell in normal table :

```
<table width="100%" class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in MyRecCollection[0]">{{header}}</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in MyRecCollection | filter:searchText">
   <td ng-repeat="cell in row">{{cell}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

MyApp.controller('dataShow', function ($scope, $http) {
    //$scope.gridheader = ['Name','City','Country']
        $http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_MYSQL.php').success(function (data) {

                $scope.MyRecCollection = data;
        })

        });
```

JSON Data :

```
[{
    "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "City": "Berlin",
    "Country": "Germany"
}, {
    "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
    "City": "Luleå",
    "Country": "Sweden"
}, {
    "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
    "City": "México D.F.",
    "Country": "Mexico"
}, {
    "Name": "Ernst Handel",
    "City": "Graz",
    "Country": "Austria"
}, {
    "Name": "FISSA Fabrica Inter. Salchichas S.A.",
    "City": "Madrid",
    "Country": "Spain"
}, {
    "Name": "Galería del gastrónomo",
    "City": "Barcelona",
    "Country": "Spain"
}, {
    "Name": "Island Trading",
    "City": "Cowes",
    "Country": "UK"
}, {
    "Name": "Königlich Essen",
    "City": "Brandenburg",
    "Country": "Germany"
}, {
    "Name": "Laughing Bacchus Wine Cellars",
    "City": "Vancouver",
    "Country": "Canada"
}, {
    "Name": "Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti",
    "City": "Bergamo",
    "Country": "Italy"
}, {
    "Name": "North/South",
    "City": "London",
    "Country": "UK"
}, {
    "Name": "Paris spécialités",
    "City": "Paris",
    "Country": "France"
}, {
    "Name": "Rattlesnake Canyon Grocery",
    "City": "Albuquerque",
    "Country": "USA"
}, {
    "Name": "Simons bistro",
    "City": "København",
    "Country": "Denmark"
}, {
    "Name": "The Big Cheese",
    "City": "Portland",
    "Country": "USA"
}, {
    "Name": "Vaffeljernet",
    "City": "Århus",
    "Country": "Denmark"
}, {
    "Name": "Wolski Zajazd",
    "City": "Warszawa",
    "Country": "Poland"
}]
```

Answer (score 4):

To create HTML table using JSON, we will use `ngRepeat` directive of AngularJS.

**Example**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<table border="1">
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>{{x.Name}}</td>
<td>{{x.City}}</td>
<td>{{x.Country}}</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
      { "Name" : "Max Joe", "City" : "Lulea", "Country" : "Sweden" },
      { "Name" : "Manish", "City" : "Delhi", "Country" : "India" },
      { "Name" : "Koniglich", "City" : "Barcelona", "Country" : "Spain" },
      { "Name" : "Wolski", "City" : "Arhus", "Country" : "Denmark" }
    ];
});
```

In above example I have created table from json. I have taken reference from 
http://www.tutsway.com/create-html-table-using-json-in-angular-js.php

Answer (score 2):

**Angular 2 or 4:**

There's no more ng-repeat, it's *ngFor now in recent Angular versions!

```
<table style="padding: 20px; width: 60%;">
    <tr>
      <th  align="left">id</th>
      <th  align="left">status</th>
      <th  align="left">name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of myJSONArray">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.status}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Used this simple JSON:

```
[{"id":1,"status":"active","name":"A"},
{"id":2,"status":"live","name":"B"},
{"id":3,"status":"active","name":"C"},
{"id":6,"status":"deleted","name":"D"},
{"id":4,"status":"live","name":"E"},
{"id":5,"status":"active","name":"F"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

To render any json in tabular format:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.records[0]">{{key}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.records">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in value">
          {{value}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[See complete code in detail with other features](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1220/angularjs-render-any-json-to-table-add-edit-remove-rows-and-more)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$http.get()` method to fetch your `JSON` file. Then assign response data to a `$scope` object. In `HTML` to create table use ng-repeat for $scope object. `ng-repeat` will loop the rows in-side this loop you can bind data to columns dynamically.

I have checked your code and you have created static table

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Relationship</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="indivisual in members">
<td>{{ indivisual.Name }}</td>
<td>{{ indivisual.Relation }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

so better your can go to my code to create dynamic table as per data you column and row will be increase or decrease..

Comment: Th is static in your code.. it should be dynamic as per data increase the column